# Convert from physical Windows Server 2012 r2 to Virtual Box

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, virtualbox

Hye, I trying to convert my windows server 2012 r2 to make it virtual by using virtual box software. I already read about using hyper-v but my server management does not have it. I thought it already in windows server by default. I want to dowload it but the size is 1gb, its just too big (for me). So if I using disk2vhd software and choose format .vhd for my choosen partition, is the windows server 2012 virtualization will work in virtual box ? because .vhdx only work on hyper-v.

THANK YOU FOR YOUR ANSWER :)

Answer (score 1):

Yep, Virtualbox supports VHD.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VirtualBox#Device_virtualization